# changing navigation dropdown box highlight color

Tags: html, colors, navbar, dropdown, highlight

```
   /* Resets */
ul,
ol,
li,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
pre,
form,
body,
html,
p,
blockquote,
fieldset,
input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a img {
  border: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Global */
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
a {
  color: #66ff00;
  -webkit-transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  transition: color 200ms ease-in;
}
a:hover,
.wsite-com-link:hover .wsite-com-link-text {
  color: #66ff00;
}
h2 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #ff6600;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
p,
div.paragraph {
  line-height: 1.8em;
}
blockquote {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  color: #ff0000;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  border-left: 0 !important;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  line-height: 1.65em;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: .95em;
  color: #66ff00;
}
blockquote:before {
  content: '\201C';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
blockquote:after {
  content: '\02EE';
  right: 0;
  bottom: -0.45em;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #ff0000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  border-radius: 0;
}
input[type="radio"]:after {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
}
input[type="radio"]:checked:after {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: @linkcolor;
  border: 4px solid #e8e8e8;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:after {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 6px;
  border: solid @LinkColor;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
}
select {
  text-indent: .01px;
  text-overflow: '';
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder,
:-moz-placeholder,
::-moz-placeholder,
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  background: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: right 610ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0.55, 1);
  -moz-transition: right 610ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0.55, 1);
  -ms-transition: right 610ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0.55, 1);
  -o-transition: right 610ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0.55, 1);
  transition: right 610ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0.55, 1);
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Header */
.wsite-header-section {
  position: relative;
  background: url(images/default-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.wsite-header-section:before,
.splash-page .header-wrap:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
}
.wsite-section-bg-color:before {
  display: none;
}
.header-wrap #logo {
  padding: 10px 0!important;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Cookie', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
.header-wrap #logo a {
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in;
}
.header-wrap #logo a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.header-wrap #logo img {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 40px;
}
.header-wrap #logo #wsite-title {
  display: block;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.header-wrap #logo img {
  max-height: 40px;
}
.header-wrap .wsite-logo {
  padding: 30px 0 0px;
}
.header-wrap .nav-wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff6600;
  text-align: center;
}
.header-wrap label.hamburger {
  display: none;
}
/* Nav */
.menu {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 102, 0, 0.95);
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 0;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.menu a {
  color: #ff6600;
}
.menu .wsite-menu-default li a {
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in border-bottom;
  letter-spacing: .03em;
}
.menu .wsite-menu-default li a:hover,
.menu .wsite-menu-default li#active a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff6600;
}
.menu .wsite-menu-default span li {
  margin-right: 40px!important;
}
.menu .wsite-menu-default span:last-child li,
.menu .wsite-menu-default li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
/* Search */
.search {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.search .wsite-search + .menu {
  text-align: left;
}
.search .wsite-search-input {
  width: 140px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 13px 10px !important;
  background: transparent;
  color: #66ff00;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
}
.search .wsite-search-button {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url(images/search.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px;
  margin: 15px 7px 0 3px;
}
#wsite-header-search-form {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(116, 116, 116, 0.15);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(116, 116, 116, 0.15);
}
/* Social */
.wsite-social-item,
#wsite-com-product-social-sharing a {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
.wsite-social-item:hover,
#wsite-com-product-social-sharing a:hover {
  color: #66ff00;
}
.navmobile-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
/* Subnav */
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu {
  margin-top: 0px!important;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a {
  font-family: 'Lato-light', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ff6600;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 0 !important;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  border: none;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li {
  border: 0px solid #ff6600;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li + li {
  border-top: none;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  right: 0px;
  display: inline-block !important;
  padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;`enter code here`
        }
```

I need to change subnav dropdown box background highlight color having no luck.I beleive it defaults to a white color and I would like to change it to a black solid color. I would be most grateful of any help provided. Thanks in advance!
Here is the link to my site to allow you to see it in action.http://www.727customz.info/

Comment: Can you post your HTML ?

Comment: this is my html?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#weebly-menus .weebly-menu li a:hover, #wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover {
background: #xxx;
}
```

The current style is:

```
#weebly-menus .weebly-menu li a:hover, #wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover {
background: #e3e3e3;
}
```

If this doesn't fix it, try adding **!important** to it like this:

```
#weebly-menus .weebly-menu li a:hover, #wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover {
    background: #xxx !important;
    }
```

Comment: are you on line 271? do not see that line?

Comment: That's what I gathered from inspecting your site. Didn't really take the time to look through your page long css.

Comment: }
.menu .wsite-menu-default li a:hover,
.menu .wsite-menu-default li#active a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff6600; this is 271 and surrounding html

Comment: .menu a {
  color: #ff6600;
}
.menu .wsite-menu-default li a {
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in border-bottom;
  letter-spacing: .03em;
}
.menu .wsite-menu-default li a:hover,
.menu .wsite-menu-default li#active a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff6600;
}                     this is where i believe the issue is..sorry new and self taught to!

Answer (score 0):

```
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover {
  color: #66ff00; 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li #active a 
{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff6600; 
  color: #66ff00;                  this is the text used to correct the issue!
}
```